# フォルダが階層になっている場合のルーティングエラーについて質問させてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails

このような階層になっているフォルダがあり、`yamaneco/index.html.erb`から`yamaneco/users/index.html.erb`にリンクを貼ったのですが、ルーティングエラーとなってしまいます。
もしかしたら上の階層に上がっていっているのかも知れません。

初歩的な躓きで申し訳ありません。よろしくお願いいたします。

project/app/views
├── yamaneco
│   ├── index.html.erb
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── detail.html.erb
│   │   ├── edit.html.erb
│   │   ├── index.html.erb
│   │   └── new.html.erb
│   └── users
│       ├── detail.html.erb
│       ├── edit.html.erb
│       ├── index.html.erb
│       └── new.html.erb
.

#### 表示されるエラー

Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/users"
Rails.root: /Users/yamaneco3/project

#### routes.rb まず最初に書いたものです

```
get 'users/' => 'users#index'
```

#### routes.rb namespaceを追加して少し手を加えてみました

```
namespace :gatto do
  get 'users/', to: 'yamaneco/users#index'
end
```

### users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

### yamaneco/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to("ユーザー一覧はこちらから", "/users/") %>
```

### yamaneco/users/index.html.erb

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= link_to(user.name, "/users/#{user.id}") %>
 <% end %>
```

`routes.rb`の記載が間違っているのだと思いますが、他にも間違っているところはありますでしょうか？

Comment: フォルダに関しては「断層」ではなく「階層」と呼ぶ方が一般的だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。修正いたします。

Answer (score 1):

`namespace`を与えているのでURLがおそらく `gatto/users/`になっているのが原因かと思われます。

現在有効になっているURL一覧はサーバーを起動した状態で`/rails/info/routes`にアクセスすれば見ることが出来るのでそちらで確認しながらリンクを修正したらどうでしょうか？